# Understanding intuitive algebraic geometry , how does a surface of genus n-1 transform into a surface of genus 2?

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I was going through the following lecture notes to familiarize myself with the motivation and intuition of Algebraic geometry :

[https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/~gathmann/class/alggeom-2014/alggeom-2014.pdf](https://www.mathematik.uni-kl.de/%7Egathmann/class/alggeom-2014/alggeom-2014.pdf)

[image]

[image]

The above example is presented as the first illustration .

I could understand that for a given value of $\ x_1 $ and a given value of $\ n $ , I can obtain two values of $\ x_2 $ which satisfy the equation .  However , I am a bit confused about the meaning of the following statement :

"It seems that $\ C_n $ looks like two copies of the complex plane with the copy of each of the points  1, 2 ,.... $\ 2n $ identified "

A question here is :
How are the two copies of complex plane obtained ?

I understand that in topological sense the identification of the so derived planes  involve sticking similar points to together .  However , I am not sure what are the two copies of complex plane here .

Secondly , when going around a point is being mentioned , I guess mathematically it refers to a rotation about the point . but when the author goes on to to prepare the correct topological picture (whose reason for correctness admittedly I do not understand ) another question that arises is as follows :

Why the two planes are being cut about the intervals [1,2] ...[2n -1 ,2n] ?

I can see this yielding a surface with n -1 holes but I could not understand the following :

how  do these n -1 holes transfer into 2 holes on compactification  ?

I beg pardon if the framing of the question creates any problem which stems from my  immaturity around these topics . I guess this example was used to illustrate the how the subject is related to topology and hence I thought the main goal should be to understand the transformation of the surface of genus $\ n -1 $ to a surface of genus $\ 2 $ but I realized in between that it hinges around clarity on the first two sub-questions of here and so this might have proved detrimental to highlighting the direction of this question .

-------------------POST SUGGESTIONS AND COMMENTS----------

Post the helpful comments from Tabes and bonsoon, I understand that the two holes in surface of genus 2 are obtained from the three handles yielded by the three holes ,when seen from a different view ,in surface of genus 3. (Is there a general name for this process  ? ) .

However , I am curious to know what happened to the three holes in the surface of genus 3 . Should I understand that it is still present ?

I understand that as at points 1 ,2 ...2n there is only one value of x2 , hence these points are glued together in both the copies of the complex plane  but I am not clear why are the cuts being made along these intervals ? Will it be right to say that the cuts being made are a part of the gluing process , as only the points 1 , 2, ...2n are the only points in both the planes which should be in contact ?

Comment: In the above figures they take $n=3$ (mentioned end of first paragraph after the thick line), so gluing two sheets with 3 holes and compactifying we get 2 holes. In general, the procedure above takes two sheets with $n$ holes, glue them accordingly, and then compactifying to get $n-1$ holes.

Comment: @bonsoon : Why does compactification lead to 2 holes ?

Comment: One thing that might clear this up is that between the upper right image (to the right of the arrow labeled "glue") and the lower left image (to the left of the arrow labeled "add points at infinity"), the imaginary camera has rotated. The three holes you see in the former are the three "necks" in the latter.

Comment: @TabesBridges : Which part are you referring to as necks ? I apologize if I should have understood .

Comment: @TabesBridges  : Are you referring to the part highlighted in blue in the following link  https://pasteboard.co/JHKY3iY.png

Comment: Yes, the three grey bits that you've marked in blue are the three necks.

Comment: @TabesBridges : Thanks a lot . Why are these necks coming about ? I guess it is because of gluing with the  integer points identified . but I am not completely clear on how the two copies of the planes  are coming up .

Comment: @TabesBridges : I notice here that the three holes got transformed to two holes from a different view and on compactification it looks like the three holes were never there or got completely covered up  .  I have read about scenarios ,where these holes (genus) are not easily apparent  , in intuitive lectures on homology or algebraic topology . With my naivette , I would like to ask is this one of such scenarios ?

Comment: 1) Yes, the necks arise from gluing the intervals between integer points. 2) The two copies of the plane arise fundamentally from the $y^2$ term. Since any nonzero complex number has two distinct square roots, this term indicates that we are building a double cover which is branched precisely at those points where the right hand side of the defining equation vanishes. 3) The top down view in the picture with three holes is a view of what becomes the "inside" of the compactified surface.

Comment: @TabesBridges : Why are the two planes cut about the intervals [0,1] , [1,2] ...[2n-1 , 2n] ? Your emphasis on the phrase "inside" hints at some technicality around it . Could you write a bit more on "inside" or point to some source where I can read more about it  ?

Comment: @TabesBridges : I am sorry I missed asking what happened to the three holes , are they still there ?